# Playframework get List of Objects as Options in select

Tags: java, forms, playframework-2.1

I am using Playframework 2.1.1 and Java. I am trying to fill a selectbox with data I retrieve from a database using the Play formhelpers

Here is some code if the view:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Admin.submitUnit) {
    @helper.select(
        field = unitForm("metaunit"),
        options = options(Metaunit.find)
    )

    ...
}
```

And the Method to retrieve Metaunits from db:

```
public static List<Metaunit> find(){
    Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("SELECT e FROM Metaunit e");
    return (List<Metaunit>)query.getResultList();
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following Error-Message:

> Overloaded method value [apply] cannot be applied to (java.util.List[models.Metaunit])

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look into `computer-database-jpa` sample ie. [`options()` method in `Company` model](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/computer-database-jpa/app/models/Company.java) in general it returns `Map<String, String>`.

As you can see in the [editForm view](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/computer-database-jpa/app/views/editForm.scala.html), usage is pretty similar to your.

Note: probably you Metaunit is connected with some M-M relation, in that case most probably you will need to use `unitForm("metaunit.id")` as a field's value

Comment: Thanks, your link to the "options() method in Company model" was exactly what I was looking for!